# Can't access some sites after connecting to VPN

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn

Like the title says, after connecting to my work's VPN I can't access some sites that I could 2 days ago. I tried connecting from another computer (using the same credentials), and everything works as expected, so it seems that something is wrong with my main computer.

I have used the build-in Windows 10 VPN but also tried [SmartVPN](https://www.draytek.com/products/smart-vpn-client/) (which also creates a VPN connection using the build-in Windows 10 VPN, but I thought I should give it a try). I've also made sure to use the default gateway on remote network.

**Things I've noticed:**

- I **can** access `google.com`, `youtube.com`
- I **can't** access `github.com`, `monday.com`
- I **can** ping `github.com`, `monday.com` succesfully

I've also tried multiple browsers after the above results, because a successful `ping` didn't make sense to me, but no luck there.

**VPN Type**: L2TP/IPsec with pre-shared key

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"? What happens in the browser when you try to do so?

Comment: @PhilippNagel It keeps loading without any response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by reducing my VPN's interface **[MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)** to `1360`.

`ping` sends 32 bytes by default, while the interface uses the MTU value which in my case (VPN interface) was `1400`. (I found it with `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces` **while connected to VPN**)

So trying to `ping github.com` (which was successful before) like `ping -f -l 1400 github.com`, I was sending 1400 bytes of data and this was failing.

I tried reducing this value till it was successful and then I changed my default MTU for the VPN interface to this value `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Name of VPN Interaface Here" mtu=1360 store=persistent`